# float:left for an element with width:100%

Tags: css, grid, css-float

What is the reason of using `float:left` for an element with `width:100%` in the 1140px Grid V2 by Andy Taylor https://github.com/andytlr/cssgrid

```
.row .twelvecol {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If for no other reason, probably consistency. Since all the other column numbers have to be floated (to get them as column groups across the row), it may be simply so that the full width column `.twelvecol` would have the same `float` applied, therefore being less likely to cause issues of it behaving differently with its wrappers or content compared to other column groupings.

[Look at this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KRS5a/1/) even in a modern browser (Firefox 18) and note how the second full width row (the third row of the example) is not showing its yellow background color because the float was removed from it but it holds a floated element in it. This would be the type of issue avoided by putting a float on it.

Comment: Can it be related to the old IE float model bugs?

Comment: @Alex: I added a fiddle example to show a case where not having a float would cause a rendering issue. It is not just an "old IE" thing, it is a `float` thing for all browsers.